# How can set property in trigger, if it's null?

Tags: wpf, triggers, null, properties

How can set property in trigger, if it's null?

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource ContextMenu}"/>
     </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Are you trying to set ContextMenu, only if the user hasn't set it?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to set ContextMenu, only if the user hasn't set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the ContextMenu directly in your Style like so:

```
<Style ...>
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource ContextMenu}"/>
</Style>
```

If the user sets the ContextMenu explicitly, then it will take precedence over the Style setter. See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) for the order or precedence. Your Style setter falls under #8, while a user setting is at #3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=ContextMenu}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource ContextMenu}"/>
     </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But in reality you should be setting the context menu in the control's style and then any user of the control can override it in a derived style or in the control attributes.

Comment: I tried to do it. See this issue: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294094/how-to-override-contextmenu-in-global-style-wpf)

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate. In the example you link to the issue is about basing a style on a base style. Is that working for you? In this question I think it's more a question of style triggers. I appreciate the up vote, but I'd like to know that the solution was useful.

Comment: This solution generate StackOverflow exception.

Comment: That sounds like your DynamicResource is null. Another way to go about it is to set the context menu in your style. Hook into the changed event for the underlying dependency property and then if it gets changed to null , coerce it to your resource.

Comment: Your trigger is no good. When ContextMenu is null, the Setter will set it to a non-null value, which invalidates the trigger, which reverts the Setter, which causes ContextMenu to be null again, etc.